# How to fetch Azure devops service connection id

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created a new service connection in Azure devops I want to fetch it's id unable to find it anywhere in Azure devops portal

Comment: fairly certain its not exposed on the portal

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following endpoint to get the id,

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

According to **[`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)**, it will return a json as

> {   "count": 1,   "value": [
>       {
>         "data": {
>           "SubscriptionId": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012",
>           "SubscriptionName": "TestSubscriptionName",
>           "environment": "AzureCloud"
>         },
>         "id": "4b16dc87-22a0-45f9-82d8-2e295c4597c6",
>         "name": "TestEndpoint",
>         "type": "Azure",
>         "url": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
>         "createdBy": {
>           "id": "4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
>           "uniqueName": "fabfiber@outlook.com",
>           "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227",
>           "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
>           "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227"
>         },
>         "authorization": {
>           "scheme": "Certificate"
>         },
>         "isReady": true
>       }   ] }